# about thread, sleep and block

Tags: ubuntu, operating-system

when you compile this Thread.c I wonder why this sequence is coming out

I think because of sleep(). It makes the block but I can't figure out correctly... and if i compile it over and over again

will the sequence be changed?? I can only get a AAA BBB CCC  plz Help me

the code is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <unistd.h>





void *thread_entry(void *ptr)
{
char *name = (char *)ptr;

printf("%s-A\n", name);

sleep(1); //sched_yield();

printf("%s-B\n", name);

sleep(1); //sched_yield();

printf("%s-C\n", name);
  }


int main()
{
 #define MAX_THREAD 3
 pthread_t thread[MAX_THREAD];
char *thread_name[MAX_THREAD] = {"thread1", "thread2", "thread3"};
int i;

for (i = 0; i < MAX_THREAD; i++)
    pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, thread_entry, thread_name[i]);

for (i = 0; i < MAX_THREAD; i++)
    pthread_join(thread[i], NULL);

return 0;
```

}

Comment: Make it clear what you want to achieve in the big picture, what the code is for, what you want it to return and what it actually does.

Comment: @Aziuth I want to know why the sequence is AAA BBB CCC ....... I am so sorry can u explain it detail?

Comment: Ok, to explain it: Stack Overflow is not some cheap chat or forum. If you ask a question, it is your job to elaborate, to be as precise as possible. You should start by reading [How To Ask Good Questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). One thing, for example, you should start to write proper english, as far as you can. Language barrier is okay, writing "plz" instead of "please" is lazy. Your question should read like "In order to achieve this, I did that. I expected the following code to return the following output, but instead it did this and that."

Comment: You start by "when you compile this Thread.c I wonder why this sequence is coming out". This is lazy language. No matter where you learned english, you know that sentences begin capitalized. But the real problem is the second part. "this sequence" - which one? There is no sequence. I could compile your code and run it, but that is not my job. It's your job to write "If you compile and run this code, it produces...". Look at some other question and edit yours. Take on the standard Stack Overflow guideline: Act as if you'd talk to a busy colleague at your job.

Comment: @Aziuth I am so sorry I didn't know that. I have just read How to Ask Good Questioin. I will rewrite this one. So sorry to disturb you